Differential equation with factorization of operator
Solve $(3x^2D^2+(2+6x-6x^2)D-4)y=F(D)y=0$.
Earlier I tried to factorize $F(D)=0$ so that I can get 2 factors and then apply bernoullis equation twice. But the factorization part is the main difficulty here since it is a teo variable expression. One solution I thought of is to use power series but it seems to be overkill. So I expect a solution which will factorize $F(D)$ so that the rest just becomes a simple linear differential equation.

Don't overthink too much : $F(D) = 3x^2D^2 + (2+6x-6x^2)D - 4$ is a quadratic expression in $D$, that is why it has to be factorized as $F(D) = (\alpha D+\beta)(aD+b)$, which acts as follows :
$$
F(D)y = \alpha ay'' + (\alpha a' + \alpha b + \beta a)y' + (\alpha b' + \beta b)y,
$$
hence the system
$$
\begin{cases}
   \alpha a = 3x^2 \\
   \alpha a' + \alpha b + \beta a = 2 + 6x - 6x^2 \\
   \alpha b' + \beta b = -4
\end{cases},
$$
which is solved by
$$
\begin{cases}
   \alpha = 1 \\
   \beta = -2 
\end{cases}
\quad\&\quad
\begin{cases}
   a = 3x^2 \\
   b = 2
\end{cases},
$$
i.e. $F(D) = (D-2)(3x^2D+2)$.

I think there is a mistake,the equation consists of $5$ terms but yours has only 4 terms as you can see,I think you are missing the $6xD$ term.

@a_i_r  My parametrization generates six terms and $6xD$ is represented by the term $\alpha a'y'$.

But $F(D)=(D-2)(3x^2D+2)=3x^2D^2+2D-6x^2D-4$ which is missing the $6xD$ term

@MarkusScheuer. Was your comment addressed to OP instead ?

@a_i_r. You cannot distribute as such, because $x$ and $D$ don't commute. Indeed, the "problematic" term is given by $D(3x^2D) = D(3x^2)D + 3x^2D(D) = 6xD + 3x^2D^2$ thanks to the product rule. Indeed, expressions including operators cannot be manipulated alone as you did, but they are always considered implicitly through their action on a function.

@Abezhiko:  Yes, I see you know the operator rules like $Dx = I + xD$. (+1)
